# Is this the correct way to obtain an AWS read-only presigned URL in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, cloudflare-r2

```js
import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand, S3ClientConfig } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { getSignedUrl } from '@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner';


const s3Configuration: S3ClientConfig = {
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: '<ACCESS_KEY_ID>',
        secretAccessKey: '<SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>'
    },
    region: '<REGION>',
};
const s3 = new S3Client(s3Configuration);
const command = new GetObjectCommand({Bucket: '<BUCKET>', Key: '<KEY>' });
const url = await getSignedUrl(s3, command, { expiresIn: 15 * 60 }); // expires in seconds
console.log('Presigned URL: ', url);
```

Is this the correct way to generate read-only access to a file, preventing any user from performing write operations on it?